# $b.link(:text => "Sign up").when_present.click not working on yahoo

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to Watir WebDriver. I was playing around with this framework and I included the below code but the second line is not working

```
$b = Watir::Browser.new :ie #browser
$b.goto "www.yahoo.com" 
$b.link(:text => "Sign up").when_present.click
```

I dont know why it is not getting the sign up link. I saw the source on Yahoo and it is as follows

```
<span class="tab-caption small y-txt-2">New here? <a href="http://hsrd.yahoo.com/_ylt=A2KLtVHgLNtQHnMBTk.bvZx4/SIG=13tjppi7u/EXP=1356627552/**https%3A//edit.yahoo.com/registration%3F.src=fpctx%26.intl=us%26.done=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.yahoo.com%252F" class="y-link-1">Sign Up</a></span>
```

What is the problem with my code? I also tried without `when_present` and it says the element is not visible.

Comment: What specifically is "not working"? What happens instead of what you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locating elements via text is case-sensitive.

Since the link says "Sign Up", your locator also needs to say "Sign Up" (not "Sign up"):

```
$b.link(:text => "Sign Up").when_present.click
```

Note that if you want to make the locator case-insensitive, you can use a regular expression with the ignore case modifier:

```
$b.link(:text => /sign up/i).when_present.click
```